# How to use jQuery's .serialize function with dynamic form elements

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do I serialize dynamic form inputs?

```
<table id="mytable">
<form id="myform">
 <tbody>
   <tr><td><input type="text" name="row0"></td></tr> <!-- dynamically generated -->
   <tr><td><input type="text" name="row1"></td></tr> <!-- dynamically generated -->
   <tr><td><input type="text" name="row2"></td></tr> <!-- dynamically generated -->
   <tr><td><input type="text" name="row3"></td></tr> <!-- dynamically generated -->
 </tbody>
 <tfoot>
   <tr><td><input type="button" id="save" value="SAVE"></td></tr> <!-- static -->
 </tfoot>
</form>
</table>
```

I want to use jQuery to load info from php

```
$('#save').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "post.php",
     data: $('#myform').serialize(),
     success: function(msg){
         console.log(msg);
     }
   });
});
```

This would work no problem if the rows were not dynamically generated, but I can't figure out how to access or serialize the dynamic content.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Serializing dynamic contents works fine the way you have it (since you're doing it in a `click` handler, not on load)...but you need to have a valid `<form>` element wrapped around the `<table>`, like this:

```
<form id="myform">
<table id="mytable">
 <tbody>
   <tr><td><input type="text" name="row0"></td></tr> <!-- dynamically generated -->
   <tr><td><input type="text" name="row1"></td></tr> <!-- dynamically generated -->
   <tr><td><input type="text" name="row2"></td></tr> <!-- dynamically generated -->
   <tr><td><input type="text" name="row3"></td></tr> <!-- dynamically generated -->
 </tbody>
 <tfoot>
   <tr><td><input type="button" id="save" value="SAVE"></td></tr> <!-- static -->
 </tfoot>
</table>
</form>
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/evswQ/).

Comment: It was picking it up when it wasn't dynamically generated. I wonder why it has problems when it's dynamic.

Comment: @polyhedron - With invalid markup things are unporedictable...it may have placed the form differently in the DOM with the elements inside before.

Comment: @polyhedron: if that solved your problem, you should mark it as the accepted answer so that others who have this problem can easily see the solution.